# How could I populate a hidden field when a link is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, client-side

I am working on a FYI page that has large list of top-tiered links. Under these top-tier links, there are more links that usually go out to external websites.  Currently, the way I handle populating the second-tier is as such: I query my database for all the top-tier links, then I construct an unordered list. Each list item has the format of:

```
<li class="multicolumnlistitem"><a href="linkpage.aspx?s={0}">Link Text</a></li>
```

Where {0} is the ID of the item. I would like to eliminate the need to pass the ID in the URL. It was suggested to me that I use client-side scripts to dynamically fill a hidden field with the value when one of the links are clicked, then read the form value on the linkpage.

Any ideas/examples/resources will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

## Update

Here is the code that I have gotten down so far:

```
<form id="stateform" action="StateFyi/StateFyiView.aspx" method="post">
<p>
    <input type="hidden" id="idfield" name="s" runat="server" />
    <%
        GSDataLayer.Fyi.States StateManager = new GSDataLayer.Fyi.States();

        var stateList = StateManager.GetStateList();

        foreach (GSDataLayer.Fyi.States.State s in stateList)
        {
            stateListOutput.Text +=
            string.Format("<li class=\"multicolumnlistitem\"><a href=\"javascript:document.getElementById('{0}').value='{1}';document.stateform.submit();\">{2}</a></li>\n",
            new string[] {idfield.ClientID, s.ID.ToString(), s.Name});
        }        
    %>
    <ul class="multicolumnlist">
        <asp:Literal ID="stateListOutput" runat="server" Text="No Items!" />
    </ul>
</p>
</form>
```

The only remaining hurdle is the javascript (either in the above format, or the original `document.getElementById('stateform')`) returns null for the form. I cannot add "runat=server" to this form as there is already a form on the page. This preexisting form is required by the CMS I am using to function properly.  Any ideas on where to go from here?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do it.  Otherwise your site will be worthless with Javascript disabled.

Comment: Good point. Will take this under consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
<form id="myform" action="linkpage.aspx" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" id="idfield" name="s" />
</form>
...
<li class="multicolumnlistitem"><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('idfield').value='0';document.getElementById('myform').submit();">Link Text</a></li>
```

Comment: Something like this, yes. However, it is not submitting just yet. I will have to see if I can see why not and then I will post back.

Comment: FireBug is saying: "document.getElementById("idfield") is null"

Comment: And according to the source view: <input id="ctl00_Content_ctl00_idfield" type="hidden" name="ctl00$Content$ctl00$idfield"/>. Do I have to accommodate for the extra text ASP puts in the id field?

Comment: yeah, I suppose so. I'm good with JS but I don't write ASP. If the ASP is giving you id="ctl00_Content_ctl00_idfield" then you'll have to use document.getElementById('ctl00_Content_ctl00_idfield')... you might also want to check if it changes the ID field of the form. Hopefully some other commenter will know why ASP is mucking around with your IDs.

Comment: I believe it has to do with master pages and how they organize their controls. What I will have to do is retrieve the list, then use 'idfield.ClientID()' to get the name of the control as ASP assigns it. Will report back with results.

Comment: Looks like you use server-side input field ("asp:input" instead of "input"). Since it's client-side scripting, it may be easier here to use plain-old html input field, not asp.net one.

Comment: Even 'idfield.Parent' is null :(